# Why can't Webpack resolve ‘babel-loader’?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

When I configure Webpack for this code base, Webpack complains that it `Can't resolve 'babel-loader'`. What exactly is failing, and how can I ask Webpack what its complaint is?

The Webpack configuration:

```javascript
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './source/main.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'source'),
            '/usr/share/javascript',
            '/usr/lib/nodejs',
        ],
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // Transform JSX with React.
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                },
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

The entry module:

```javascript
// source/main.jsx

"use strict";

import Application from './components/Application';

const applicationElement = <Application />;
ReactDOM.render(
    applicationElement,
    document.getElementById('application'),
);
```

Is the problem something like a search path, and if so why can't the error tell me what setting I need to correct?

The `babel-loader` module is definitely installed. (I therefore don't want to install it again – so `npm install` won't help – I am trying to tell Webpack to use it from the already-installed location.) Its package definition is at `/usr/lib/nodejs/babel-loader/package.json`.

I've pointed Webpack's resolver there – instead of its default resolver behaviour – using the `resolve.modules` list of search paths. Correct?

So the resolver should be able to find it there by the specified search path `/usr/lib/nodejs` and the name `babel-loader`, no?

(This raises a separate question, about how to [convince Webpack to just tell me what it's looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884584/convince-webpack-to-explain-its-cant-resolve-foo-error) so it can be diagnosed more easily.)

How can I **tell Webpack the specific location it should use to resolve that `babel-loader` name**?

Comment: Is this relevant? https://github.com/petehunt/jsx-loader

Comment: @Tico, no, it isn't (the error still occurs). I see that the use of “jsx-loader” was a distraction, though, so I've updated the description to hopefully focus on the relevant question. Thanks.

Comment: nice! This might help a little: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1083

Comment: could you post your package.json, at least the part relevant to babel-loader?

Comment: But there is  a reference on the package.json of your project, correct? what version ?

Comment: @facundo: “there is a reference on the package.json of your project, correct?” — I'm deploying this to the browser, not Node, and so have not written a ‘package.json’ for this code base.

Comment: having "package.json" doesn't mean that you must deploy to node, you can deploy to a filesystem and open the files in browser. I imagen that the 'babel-loader' webpack is invoking is an npm package. Webpack needs to know where to look for 'babel-loader'. Have you you linked your 'babel-loader' package to your project ? Or are you expecting webpack to look for 'babel-loader' at '/usr/lib/nodejs/babel-loader/'?

Comment: @facundo: “are you expecting webpack to look for 'babel-loader' at '/usr/lib/nodejs/babel-loader/'?” — I expect Webpack to tell me where it's looking, so that I can find out why it's not finding the library.

Comment: Webpack default behaviour is to check to see if the current directory it is is in has the module available in the folder *node_modules* and if not it goes up the a directory and checks there again.

Comment: @bignose you have such a miss conception on what webpack is. You must have a `package.json` in your directory, or at least a node_modules folder with those dependencies. You are obliged to have

Comment: Okay, I have added a Node.JS metadata file. The same error occurs, with no change, so I'm no closer to understanding what Webpack wants.

Comment: the normal thing to do is to type `npm install babel-loader --save-dev` in your terminal. which will download babel-loader from the npm-registry into your node_modules-folder and it'll also automatically update your package.json to include "devDependencies":[ "babel-loader":"someversionnumber" ],

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Webpack configuration setting `resolve` is for modules that are imported. The loaders are resolved differently; [the `resolveLoader` setting](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveloader) configures how to resolve the loaders specifically.

So, adding `resolveLoader` to the Webpack configuration works:

```javascript
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './source/main.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        // Configure how Webpack finds modules imported with `import`.
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'source'),
            '/usr/share/javascript',
            '/usr/lib/nodejs',
        ],
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        // Configure how Webpack finds `loader` modules.
        modules: [
            '/usr/lib/nodejs',
        ],
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // Transform JSX with React.
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                },
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `webpack.config` you're looking for is the following:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
  ]
}
```

Hope helps :)

Comment: Thanks. That still gives the same error (`Error: Can't resolve 'babel'`). The problem remains: Webpack isn't telling me where it looked, so I can't investigate further.

Comment: can you show me the package.json that you have? ... So I can take a look further into your problem

Comment: This code base has no ‘package.json’. I think Webpack already has all the configuration it needs; if not, that's what this question is about, how to get Webpack to tell me what it's assuming so that it can be corrected.

Comment: I think them you should have to report this as an issue, have being checking the docs and no clue, your code should work just fine