# Convince Webpack to explain its `Can't resolve 'foo'` error

Tags: javascript, webpack, diagnostics

How can I convince Webpack to, when it is going to emit `Can't resolve 'foo'`, also **emit information about *where it tried* to find** that library?

The error message `Can't resolve 'foo'` is unhelpful because it is a dead end. The reader has no clue which paths Webpack tried and failed; so there's no information to distinguish:

- The file is in a known location, Webpack found it there, but for some reason didn't use it.

  (Implies the need for diagnostic information about why it didn't use it.)
- The file is in a known location, but Webpack did not look there.

  (Implies the need for diagnostic information about what locations Webpack tried.)
- The file is not actually where the programmer thinks it is.

  (Implies the need for diagnostic information about what locations Webpack tried.)
- Something else.

How can I convince the Webpack program to **actually give diagnostic information along with** the `Can't resolve 'foo'` error, to help quickly troubleshoot and distinguish between the above conditions?

Comment: I did a quick test with Webpack 5 - and I get diagnostic info. Which Webpack version are you using?